# How to fix errors when install Angular CLI on CS50 IDE?

Tags: angular, npm, cs50

I tried installing Angular CLI on **CS50 IDE** but it keeps getting error, I have tried some

- Uninstall and do npm cache clean --force
- Then reinstall by npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

but they did not work. There are many npm WARN

Here are snapshots of terminal when I tried to install

1. npm install -g u/angular/cli@latest

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
/home/ubuntu/.npm/bin/ng -> /home/ubuntu/.npm/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@12.1.3 postinstall /home/ubuntu/.npm/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@12.1.3
added 235 packages from 180 contributors in 19.586s
```

2. ng new my-first-project

```
$ ng new my-first-project
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE my-first-project/README.md (1060 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/.gitignore (604 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/angular.json (3099 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/package.json (1087 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/tsconfig.json (783 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/.browserslistrc (703 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/karma.conf.js (1433 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/tsconfig.app.json (287 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/tsconfig.spec.json (333 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/index.html (300 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/polyfills.ts (2820 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/test.ts (743 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/environments/environment.ts (658 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/app/app.component.html (24585 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (986 bytes)
CREATE my-first-project/src/app/app.component.ts (220 bytes)
⠏ Installing packages (npm)...npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN tar ENOMEM: not enough memory, write
Killed
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The only error I see is at the bottom, “not enough memory”

Comment: I do notice that but it makes no sense as I'm using CS50, not my local computer, so the lack of memory is impossible. Many bigger projects still use CS50 and that's fine, compared to my extremely small project

Answer (score 0):

```
npm cache clean --force
npm i -g @angular/cli
```